# Sonar Custom Widget

Tags: api, widget, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I created a widget using the source code available in github. Now I'm using that widget in SonarQube V5.3. This is where I got the source code from:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin

When I use this widget it is showing up the same data across multiple projects. I would like to know if there is any way I can display different data for different projects. Please share your ideas. Below is the code that displays the ruby widget

```
    import org.sonar.api.web.AbstractRubyTemplate;
    import org.sonar.api.web.Description;
    import org.sonar.api.web.RubyRailsWidget;
    import org.sonar.api.web.UserRole;
    import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetCategory;
    import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetProperties;
    import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetProperty;
    import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetPropertyType;
    import org.sonar.api.batch.CheckProject;
    import org.sonar.api.resources.Project;
    @UserRole(UserRole.USER)
    @Description("Sample")
    @WidgetCategory("Sample")
    @WidgetProperties({
      @WidgetProperty(key = "Index",type=WidgetPropertyType.TEXT
      ),

    })
    public class OneMoreRubyWidget extends AbstractRubyTemplate implements RubyRailsWidget {

      @Override
      public String getId() {
        return "Sample";
      }

      @Override
      public String getTitle() {
        return "Sample";
      }

      @Override
      protected String getTemplatePath() {

          return "/example/Index.html.erb";
      }
    }
```

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified global scope for your widget (`@WidgetScope("GLOBAL")`) in the `.java` file, so this is a question of what's in your `.erb` file.

This [Widget Lab](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Widget+Lab+Plugin) property [widget](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-widget-lab/blob/master/src/main/resources/security_issues_tag_widget.html.erb) should give you some pointers. Specifically: you want to pick up `@project` in your widget, and query with `@project.uuid`. [Here's another](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-widget-lab/blob/master/src/main/resources/measure_bar_chart_widget.html.erb) project-level widget for comparison.

You should be aware, though, that SonarSource is actively working to remove Ruby from the platform, so at some future date, you'll probably end up re-writing your widgets (likely in pure JavaScript).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. Can you please help me understand any logic to make the widget display different widget should be written on the .erb file? This widget I'm trying to develop is a totally out of box widget. For this do I need to include anything in sonar.properties file? Please advise. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Take a look at the Widget lab plugin (docs: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Widget+Lab+Plugin).